# Python - string with many variables - which one is throwing the error?

Tags: python, string

i have a **string** with **60+ Variables** inside and sometimes it throws me an Error: 'must be real number, not str'. While i know what the error means, i don´t know which variable produces it.

**Is there a reasonable way to find the trouble making variable?**

My actual solution is to split the string up in groups and narrow it down until i find it, but thats quite tedious.

string looks like:

```
s = "%s bla bla %i some more bla %.2f etc." % \
  (test_string, \
  test_int, \
  test_float)
```

Thanks for any advice or good ideas.

Comment: I'd say avoid such monster strings to begin with and break it down into smaller pieces, perhaps even some string builder class…

Comment: Not a solution for the debugging of your current problem, but you might want to switch to f-strings for the formatting.: `s = f"{test_string} bla bla {test_int} some more bla {test_float:.2f} etc."`

Comment: thanks for the hints.
@Matthias even with f strings i don´t know which one is throwing the error, beside that i get really unreadable with the many variables.

Comment: @decez: its within a logger and i´m logging multiple values to the console in table format. that´s why its comfortable to have it in one string and not multiple small ones, as easier to overview.

Comment: When you have multiple strings to format, logging the strings will just be a case of adding them together: `s1+s2+s3+ ...`

Answer (score 0):

The error message comes from the `%f` format operator. `%s` formats a string, and `%i` formats an integer.

So you only need to check the variables that correspond to that format. In the  example, it's `test_float`.

You can use this to print the types of all the variables that correspond to `%f` formats:

```
for i, v in enumerate([var1, var2, var3]):
    if not isinstance(v, float):
        print(f"{i} {type(v)}")
```

This will tell you the indexes in the list of the variables that aren't `float`.

Comment: the thing is that 90% are float format operators.

Comment: I've added some code you can use to help.

Comment: nice idea to check them in case of error separately. thx.